# Python: Getting all the items out of a `threading.local`

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a `threading.local` object. When debugging, I want to get all the objects it contains for all threads, while I am only on one of those threads. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the pure-python version of `threading.local` (`from _threading_local import local`), this is possible:

```
for t in threading.enumerate():
    for item in t.__dict__:
       if isinstance(item, tuple):  # Each thread's `local` state is kept in a tuple stored in its __dict__
           print("Thread's local is %s" % t.__dict__[item])
```

Here's an example of it in action:

```
from _threading_local import local
import threading
import time

l = local()

def f():
   global l
   l.ok = "HMM"
   time.sleep(50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l.ok = 'hi'
    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.start()
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        for item in t.__dict__:
           if isinstance(item, tuple):
               print("Thread's local is %s" % t.__dict__[item])
```

Output:

```
Thread's local is {'ok': 'hi'}
Thread's local is {'ok': 'HMM'}
```

This is exploiting the fact that the pure-python implementation of `local` stores each thread's `local` state in the `Thread` object's `__dict__`, using a tuple object as the key:

```
>>> threading.current_thread().__dict__
{ ..., ('_local__key', 'thread.local.140466266257288'): {'ok': 'hi'}, ...}
```

If you're using the implementation of `local` written in `C` (which is usually the case if you just use `from threading import local`), I'm not sure how/if you can do it.